# Read file on the server using PHP

Tags: php

I am working on PHP. I want to read a file from a server. For example. My file is on `192.168.0.1:/myfolder/myfile.txt`. And i wan to display all the files content on PHP page, The problem is how to open the file on the server. 
i am using

`$file = fopen("192.168.0.1:/myfolder/myfile.txt","r")` or `exit("Unable to open the file!");`

But this is not working. I get error.

> PHP warning: Unable to open the file.

I also allowed couple of option in php.ini. But nothing works.

Comment: Do you have `allow_url_fopen` configuration enabled? What does `var_dump(ini_get('allow_url_fopen'));` output?

Comment: If it's on the same server why not just use a filesystem path (not an URL) and `file_get_contents()` ?

Comment: If your server is not setup with suexec, the user `nobody` or `www-data` is the one actually running PHP, and they may be blocked from making outbound requests on port 80 by the host. Look at the results of [posix_getpwnam()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-getpwnam.php) to see what user is actually running PHP.

Comment: `"192.168.0.1:/myfolder/myfile.txt"`: are you sure about this. just use '"myfile.txt"' and place .txt where your php file is

Comment: yes allow_url_fopen is enabled. And $userinfo = posix_getpwnam(""); didnot gave me any output